# Run the same test case on multiple devices in detox

Tags: detox

I would like to achieve running one example test case for multiple devices in parallel. I see that in doc there is an information about maxworkers. I add in detox config new device like 3 times add type of device and increase the number of workers to 3. Unfortunately it works only on one device. Any ideas, tips what should i do to make running tests on multiple devices in parallel? I need to run test cases for 7 emulators/devices to make sure that everything works correctly.